# Get value from radio button AND copy value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've looked all over, and can see many ways to get the value of a radio button, but not take it the next step and set the same value to a similar set of radio buttons. Copying text values works fine, just can't get the radio buttons to copy also.

EDIT:
I added the entire relevant html:

```
<div class="form-container">            
<div class="form-titles">
    <h4>Customer <span>Shipping</span> Information</h4> 
    </div>      



<div id="fillout-form"> 


        <label for="name"><span>*</span>Contact Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="company"><span>*</span>Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="50" class="required" />   
        <label for="land-line"><span>*</span>Primary Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="land-line" name="land-line" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="cell">Cell Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cell" name="cell" maxlength="50" />  
        <label for="email"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="fax">Fax:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fax" name="fax" maxlength="50" />    
        <label for="address"><span>*</span>Street Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="address-2">Street Address 2:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address-2" name="address-2" maxlength="50" />    
        <label for="city"><span>*</span>City:</label>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="state"><span>*</span>State or Province:</label>
            <input type="text" id="state" name="state" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="zip"><span>*</span>Zip / Postal Code:</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" maxlength="50" class="required" />
</div>
<div id="vertical-radio">
    <div id="radio-buttons">
        <label for="country"><span>*</span>Country:</label>
            <div id="multi-line-radio"><input type="radio" name="country" id="country" value="USA" class="required" checked >United States</div>
            <div id="multi-line-radio"><input type="radio" name="country" id="country" value="Canada" >Canada</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-container">    
<div class="form-titles">   
            <h4>Customer <span>Billing</span> Information</h4>  
        <div class="same-address">
        <input type="checkbox" name="same-address" value="same-address" id="copyCheck"><p>Same as Shipping Address?</p>
        </div>
</div>      
<div id="fillout-form"> 

        <label for="name_2"><span>*</span>Contact Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="company_2"><span>*</span>Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="company_2" name="company_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />   
        <label for="land-line_2"><span>*</span>Primary Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="land-line_2" name="land-line_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="cell_2">Cell Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cell_2" name="cell_2" maxlength="50" />  
        <label for="email_2"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email_2" name="email_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="fax_2">Fax:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fax_2" name="fax_2" maxlength="50" />    
        <label for="PO-Box_2">PO-Box:</label>
            <input type="text" id="PO-Box_2" name="PO-Box_2" maxlength="50" />                  
        <label for="address_2">Street Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address_2" name="address_2" maxlength="50" />
        <label for="address-2_2">Street Address 2:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address-2_2" name="address-2_2" maxlength="50" />    
        <label for="city_2"><span>*</span>City:</label>
            <input type="text" id="city_2" name="city_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="state_2"><span>*</span>State or Province:</label>
            <input type="text" id="state_2" name="state_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
        <label for="zip_2"><span>*</span>Zip / Postal Code:</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip_2" name="zip_2" maxlength="50" class="required" />
</div>
<div id="vertical-radio">
    <div id="radio-buttons">
        <div id="country_option_2">
        <label for="country_2"><span>*</span>Country:</label>
            <div id="multi-line-radio"><input type="radio" name="country_2" id="country_2" value="USA" class="required" checked >United States</div>
            <div id="multi-line-radio"><input type="radio" name="country_2" id="country_2" value="Canada" >Canada</div>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
$("#copyCheck").change(function() {
    if ($("#copyCheck:checked").length > 0) {
        bindGroups();
    } else {
        unbindGroups();
    }
    });
});

var bindGroups = function() {

$("input[id='name_2']").val($("input[id='name']").val());
$("input[id='company_2']").val($("input[id='company']").val());
$("input[id='land-line_2']").val($("input[id='land-line']").val());
$("input[id='cell_2']").val($("input[id='cell']").val());
$("input[id='email_2']").val($("input[id='email']").val());
$("input[id='fax_2']").val($("input[id='fax']").val());
$("input[id='address_2']").val($("input[id='address']").val());
$("input[id='address-2_2']").val($("input[id='address-2']").val());
$("input[id='city_2']").val($("input[id='city']").val());
$("input[id='state_2']").val($("input[id='state']").val());
$("input[id='zip_2']").val($("input[id='zip']").val());
$("input:radio[name=country_2]:checked").val($("input:radio[name=country]:checked").val());







 $("input[id='name']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='name_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='company']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='company_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='land-line']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='land-line_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='cell']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='cell_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='email']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='email_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='fax']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='fax_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='address']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='address_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='address-2']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='address-2_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='city']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='city_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='state']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='state_2']").val($(this).val());
});
$("input[id='zip']").keyup(function() {
    $("input[id='zip_2']").val($(this).val());
});

};

var unbindGroups = function() {
$("input[id='name']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='company']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='land-line']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='cell']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='email']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='fax']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='address']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='address-2']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='city']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='state']").unbind("keyup");
$("input[id='zip']").unbind("keyup");


   };





   });
```

Comment: Your code needs refactoring. I suggest posting a question on  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ after solving the current problem.

Comment: I added an answer below, but only used your posted `html`. If you want a more in depth solution, post all of the pertaining `html` so we can see everything in context.

Comment: added text input support and irt updating to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Close your input tags**

for example

`<input type="radio" name="country" value="Canada">`

should be

`<input type="radio" name="country" value="Canada"/>`

**IDs are unique**

and exist once, and only once, in a particular document.

for example

`<div id="radio-buttons">...</div><div id="radio-buttons">...</div>`

should be something like

`<div id="radio-buttons-1">...</div><div id="radio-buttons-2">...</div>`

or

`<div class="radio-buttons">...</div><div class="radio-buttons">...</div>`

**open your mind**

There doesn't seem to be a need to handle each of these on an individual basis, you should think *"how can i get those to copy here"* not *"lets copy this one and this one and this one..."*

which would give you jquery that looks more like this:

```
var ship = $('.form-container').eq(0).find('input'),//first fields
    bill = $('.form-container').eq(1).find('input').not('#copyCheck,#PO-Box_2');//second fields

$('#copyCheck').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { bindGroups(); }//checked:bind answers
    else { unbindGroups(); }//!checked:remove answers
});

function brains(e,i) {//runs on bindgroups and on irt
    var tc;
    if (e.is('[type=radio]')) {//if radio
        tc = e.prop('checked');//get checked
        bill.eq(i).prop('checked',tc);//add checked to corresponding element
    } else if(e.is('[type=text],[type=email]')) {//if text or email
        tc = e.val();//get value
        bill.eq(i).val(tc);//add value to corresponding element
    }
}

function bindGroups() {//copy
    ship.each(function(i){//for each input
        brains($(this),i);//run brains
        $(this).on('keyup change', function() {//on keyup or change
            brains($(this),i);//run brains
        });
    });
}

function unbindGroups() {//clear the deck
    ship.each(function(i){//for each input
        if ($(this).is('[type=radio]')) {//if radio
            bill.eq(i).prop('checked',false);//reset radio optional
        } else if($(this).is('[type=text],[type=email]')) {//if text or email
            bill.eq(i).val('');//empty text optional
        }
    }).unbind();//unbind actions
}
```

That way your not writing jquery for every element individually.

**made a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/bC3mQ/

Comment: I've added irt updates and added text input support. It will need to change for `checkboxes` and `textarea` to have support.

Comment: Thanks a million. I really appreciate you helping me with this, especially in regards to how I should look at the problem - thanks for helping me to learn!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Sometimes it's hard to look at the problem as a whole, but refactoring isn't a choice; it's a necessity. I refactored it a little more to make it easier to maintain and adapt.

Comment: Oh, I tried running it in fiddle, and on my website, but it crashes on both, if it's checked and it starts to copy information from "ship" to "bill." It usually crashes by the 3rd or 4th fill-in box. This is with using Chrome.

Comment: I apologize - it seems to work fine now. I can't tell you why when I was using fiddle before it was crashing on me. In anycase, thanks again.

Comment: well the new one is better and faster, so I'll update the answer.

Comment: And yes, much simpler!

Comment: And I got it totally working on my site. I can't thank you enough.